# xsl how to show all the attributes of the same field

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have the following field (f28) and would like to show all results that have data.
Being that already has the template to show a value and also not show value = null

My xsl.. for each field

```
 <xsl:template match="f28">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="ROW/@f1 !='NULL'">
        <xsl:element name="hasTestDegree" namespace="{namespace-uri()}#">
        <xsl:value-of select='ROW/@f1'/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

My XML:

```
<f28>
 <ROW f1='FULL' f2='NULL' f3='NULL' f4='NULL' f5='not certain' f6='BRCA1' f7='NULL'/>
 <ROW f1='FULL' f2='NULL' f3='NULL' f4='NULL' f5='no mutation' f6='BRCA2' f7='NULL'/> 
 <ROW f1='FULL' f2='NULL' f3='NULL' f4='NULL' f5='NULL' f6='p53' f7='NULL'/>
</f28>
```

I wanted the following results :

```
  <hasTestDegree>FULL</hasTestDegree>
  <hasTestResult>not certain</hasTestResult>
  <hasTestType>BRCA1</hasTestType>`

  <hasTestDegree>FULL</hasTestDegree>
  <hasTestResult>no mutation</hasTestResult>
  <hasTestType>BRCA2</hasTestType>`

  <hasTestDegree>FULL</hasTestDegree>
  <hasTestType>p53</hasTestType>`
```

Comment: Please include the desired output XML (be *exact*, no hand-waving) for your sample input, your question is ambiguous without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create templates that match the attributes in question.
2. Apply templates to the attributes.
3. That's all.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="f28">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
    <xsl:sort select="name()" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- @f1 becomes <hasTestDegree> -->
<xsl:template match="f28//@f1">
  <hasTestDegree>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </hasTestDegree>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add more templates for the other attributes... -->

<!-- any attribute with a value of 'NULL' is not output -->
<xsl:template match="@*[. = 'NULL']" />
```

Notes.

- It seems unnecessary to use `<xsl:element>` in your case, just write out the element you want to create.
- My solution relies on match specificity. The match expression `@*[. = 'NULL']` overrules `f28//@f1` for attributes that are `'NULL'`.
- The intermediate step (`<xsl:apply-templates select="ROW" />`) is necessary to make sure everything is processed in the right order.
- You could either use `<xsl:sort>` in `<xsl:apply-templates>` or use `<xsl:apply-templates>` several times in a row, if you want to determine output order manually.